# why google sign in not working in mod apk?

Tags: oauth, apk, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to change apk through apk editor but google OAuth stops working. As far as I understand, this is related to the apk signature. I changed the smali code and strings.xml for google data.

I tried to insert my sha1 key of the modified apk into firebase and google cloud, before that I changed the google services data in the apk itself. Nothing changed.

Comment: Please edit your question describe in detail what parts of the APK you have modified.